# How to correctly deallocate a shared memory between processes?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, posix, shared-memory

As I want to have a shared barrier between processes, I'm using the `shm_open`, `ftruncate`, and `mmap` system calls to create a shared memory and map it to a barrier pointer.

```
int status, fd_barr;
fd_barr = shm_open("/barrier", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
status = ftruncate(fd_barr, sizeof(pthread_barrier_t));
barrier = mmap(0, sizeof(pthread_barrier_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_barr, 0);
```

Everything works fine! My question is after destroying my barrier pointer, how should I correctly deallocate the shared memory? How could I use the `shm_unlink` and `close(fd)` functions? Which one should I call first? Which one can I call immediately after the `mmap` and which one should I call at the very end of my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Call munmap on the region.
2. Call close on the file descriptor that corresponds to fd_barr
3. Call shm_unlink on the filename "/barrier"

Note that you could unlink before you close. That would simply make the shared mem not accessible through the filesystem name. It would get deallocated when the *last* open file descriptor gets closed.